# Random Die Generator

Tags: python

Can someone tell me why my program doesn't work? Even when I set `s` as 10000.

When I printed out `wins` and `plays` it just shows up as 0 and 1.

```
def manyCraps(s):
    wins = 0
    plays = 0

    dice1 = randint(1,6)
    dice2 = randint(1,6)
    total = dice1 + dice2

    for i in range(s):
        if total == 7 or total == 11:
            wins = wins + 1
            plays = plays + 1  
        else:
            if total == 2 or total == 3 or total == 12:
                plays = plays + 1        
            else:
                plays = plays + 1
                dice3 = randint(1,6)
                dice4 = randint(1,6)
                total = dice3 + dice4
```

Comment: You never re-roll the dice when you get a 7, 11, or 2, 3, 12, so it will always win or lose after the first roll of those numbers. Printing `plays` and `wins` after the loop does print `10000` and some very wrong number.

Comment: I just realized i printed it inside the for loop, thanks